# Cannot make vc-style wrapping of git commit to work

Tags: vc

None of these functions currently perform works as I except:

```lisp
(defun vc-git-commit ()
  "Commit (via git)."
  (interactive)
  (vc-git--run-command-string nil "commit")
  (vc-dir-refresh))
(let ((map vc-dir-mode-map))
  (define-key map "c" 'vc-git-commit))

(defun vc-git-commit-amend ()
  "Commit amended (via git)."
  (interactive)
  (vc-git--run-command-string nil "commit" "--amend")
  (vc-dir-refresh))
(let ((map vc-dir-mode-map))
  (define-key map "," 'vc-git-commit-amend))

(defun vc-git-commit-amend-no-edit ()
  "Commit amended --no-edit (via git)."
  (interactive)
  (vc-git--run-command-string nil "commit" "--amend" "--no-edit")
  (vc-dir-refresh))
(let ((map vc-dir-mode-map))
  (define-key map ";" 'vc-git-commit-amend-no-edit))
```

. `vc-git-commit` has no effect, `vc-git-commit-amend` hangs, and `vc-git-commit-amend-no-edit` has not effect.

How should I modify these so that they work as `vc-next-action` does?